# Open Google Compute Engine Port 8000

Tags: port, firewall, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to set up a VM instance in Google Compute Engine. So far so good. 
Now I've installed ajenti, which requires **port 8000 for its web interface**.

I created a firewall rule for **TCP 8000**. It doesn't work. I also set up **iptables** on the server to try to fix the problem. It **![still doesn't work]**. I'm kind of desperate right now. I just want to access the web interface.

Thanks for help!

[Firewall Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0Zji.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default SSL is enabled in Ajenti. Try accessing your web page using **https**://YOURSERVERIP:8000

Answer (score 0):

The target tag you have set restricts which instances the firewall rule applies to. Ensure that your instance has the `http-server` tag.